# Python: urllib.urlencode is escaping my stuff *twice*

Tags: python, urlencode, urllib

... but it's not escaping it the same *way* twice.

I'm trying to upload ASCII output from gpg to a website. So, the bit I've got, so far, just queries the table, shows me the data it got, and then shows it to me after it encodes it for a HTTP POST request:

```
cnx = connect()
sql = ("SELECT Data FROM SomeTable")
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
for (data) in cursor:
        print "encoding : %s" % data
        postdata = urllib.urlencode( { "payload" : data } ) 
        print "encoded as %s" % postdata
```

... but what I get is:

```
encoding : -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.12 (GNU/Linux)
.... etc...

encoded as payload=%28u%27-----BEGIN+PGP+MESSAGE-----%5CnVersion%3A+GnuPG+v1.4.12+... etc ...
```

The part to notice is that the newlines aren't getting turned into %0A, like I'd expect. Instead, they're somehow getting escaped into "\n", and then the backslashes are escaped to %5C, so a newline becomes "%5Cn". Even stranger, the data gets prepended with *%28u%27*, which comes out to "*(u'*".

Oddly, if I just do a basic test with:

```
data = "1\n2"
print data
print urllib.urlencode( { "payload" : data } )
```

I get what I expect, newlines turn into %0A...

```
1
2
payload=1%0A2
```

So, my hunch is that the data element returned from the mysql query isn't the same kind of string as my literal "1\n2" (maybe a 1-element dict... dunno), but I don't have the Python kung-fu to know how to inspect it.

Anybody know what's going on, here, and how I can fix it? If not, any suggestions for how to POST this via HTTP with everything getting escaped properly?

Comment: What's with all the extra parens, like `for (data) in cursor` instead of `for data in cursor`, or `sql = ("…")` instead of `sql = "…"`? Are you expecting them to do something?

Comment: I pasted it from an example which had more elements in it... as in "for (first, last, phone) in userquery...". I figured Python needed even single items to remain inside parens in order to do the result-set-lookup weirdness that it does. Oh, the "sql = (...)" was... yeah, that was left over from something else. I was recycling some code which did an INSERT, and I was doing a cursor.execute(queryTemplate,queryValues) kind of thing.

Comment: In Python, parentheses don't make a `tuple`, commas do. So `1, 2, 3` is a `tuple`. There are some cases where you need to put a `tuple` (or other similar features like generator expressions) in parens for disambiguation, but it's still the commas that make it a `tuple`. Once you understand it that way, it makes sense that `(1,)` is a 1-element `tuple` while `(1)` is an `int`. Until you understand that, `(1,)` looks like an ugly meaningless wart that you have to memorize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `connect()` is a function from some [DB-API 2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249) compatible database interface (like the built-in `sqlite3`, or the most popular `mysql` interface), `for (data) in cursor:` is iterating `Row` objects, not strings.

When you print it out, you're effectively printing `str(data)` (by passing it to a `%s` format). If you want to encode the same thing, you have to encode `str(data)`.

However, a better way to do it is to handle the rows as rows (of one column) in the first place, instead of relying on `str` to do what you want.

PS, if you were trying to rely on tuple unpacking to make `data` the first element of each row, you're doing it wrong:

```
for (data) in cursor:
```

… is identical to:

```
for data in cursor:
```

If you want a one-element `tuple`, you need a comma:

```
for data, in cursor:
```

(You can also add the parens if you want, but they still don't make a difference either way.)

Specifically, iterating the cursor will call the optional [`__iter__`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#iter) method, which returns the cursor itself, then loop calling the [`next`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#next) method on it, which does the same thing as calling `fetchone()` until the result set is exhausted, and [`fetchone`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id20) is documented to return "a single sequence", whose type isn't defined. In most implementations, that's a special row type, like [`sqlite3.Row`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#row-objects), which can be accessed as if it were a `tuple` but has special semantics for things like printing in tabular format, allowing by-name access, etc.

Comment: Yeah... it was the comma after "data" in the for-loop. Never thought to try that because it's the exact *wrong* thing to do in Perl, which is more of my weapon of choice.